# Calculator: display single digit again after after an operation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I mean after pressing the 'equal' button the result is display, when I click another **number** it doesn't clear out the result but I don't want it to clear out when **operation symbols** like '+' or '/' are pressed. I was finishing this calculator yesterday when I realize this issue , I was playing around with `if` element in `function ans()` and I feel like I got pretty close I just couldn't get it:

```
function ud(e) {
    var currentVal = $("#display").val()
    $("#display").val(currentVal + e.data.n);
}

function ans(c) {
 var result = eval($("#display").val())
 $("#display").val(result)
 }

function clc() {
    $("#display").val('');
}

for(var i = 0; i < 0; i++) {
  $('#button' + i).click({n: i}, ud);
}
// alert('foo');
$("#button0").click({n: '0'}, ud);
$("#button1").click({n: '1'}, ud);
$("#button2").click({n: '2'}, ud);
$("#button3").click({n: '3'}, ud);
$("#button4").click({n: '4'}, ud);
$("#button5").click({n: '5'}, ud);
$("#button6").click({n: '6'}, ud);
$("#button7").click({n: '7'}, ud);
$("#button8").click({n: '8'}, ud);
$("#button9").click({n: '9'}, ud);

$("#addButton").click({n: '+'}, ud);
$("#subtractButton").click({n: '-'}, ud);
$("#multiplyButton").click({n: '*'}, ud);
$("#clearButton").click(clc);
$("#equalsButton").click(ans);
$("#divideButton").click({n: '/'}, ud);
```

Appreciate any advice one could give me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a variable to check if the current content of `#display` is a result. Furthermore I added a paremeter to the buttons `onClick` which tells the `ud` function to clear, when the current `#display` content is a result and the click event has the order to `clearOnResult`.

You should really rename your functions. You should know what they do just by reading their name. A good help here is to make a sentence beginning with "to".

E.g.:

- To calculate the result we ... (function name: calculateResult)
- To clear the Display we ... (function name clearDisplay)
- To add a symbol to the display we ... (function name: addSymbolToDisplay)

Have fun :)

```js
var isResult = false;

function ud(e) {
  const clearOnResult = e.data.clearOnResult || false; // defaults to false when not given
  
  if (clearOnResult && isResult) {
    $("#display").val("");
  }
  
  isResult = false; // the content of display is no longer a result
  
  var currentVal = $("#display").val()
  $("#display").val(currentVal + e.data.n);
}

function ans(c) {
  var result = eval($("#display").val())
  $("#display").val(result)
  
  isResult = true; // the content of display is a result now
}

function clc() {
  $("#display").val('');
}

for(var i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
  $('#button' + i).click({n: i, clearOnResult: true}, ud);
}

$("#addButton").click({n: '+'}, ud);
$("#subtractButton").click({n: '-'}, ud);
$("#multiplyButton").click({n: '*'}, ud);
$("#clearButton").click(clc);
$("#equalsButton").click(ans);
$("#divideButton").click({n: '/'}, ud);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button0">0</button>
<button id="button1">1</button>
<button id="button2">2</button>
<button id="button3">3</button>
<button id="button4">4</button>
<button id="button5">5</button>
<button id="button6">6</button>
<button id="button7">7</button>
<button id="button8">8</button>
<button id="button9">9</button>
<br /><br />
<button id="addButton">+</button>
<button id="subtractButton">-</button>
<button id="multiplyButton">*</button>
<button id="divideButton">/</button>
<button id="clearButton">C</button>
<button id="equalsButton">=</button>
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" id='display' />
```

Comment: its working! thank you very much I'll study this code!